# Android commonsware rich text editor

Tags: android, android-edittext, rich-text-editor, commonsware-cwac

I successfully used **rich edit text**. I like the effects provided in the `rich text editor`. In my project i added a bold `button` to make the text bold.

Now i am able to make bold text on selected text. Now i want to make

> the typing text after clicking the bold button like in android ever note version, also in desktop applications like m.s word etc.

How it can be made possible? Please help me.

I just tried using text watcher and in `onBeforeTextChanged`  i simply add the `typeface` property to the `RichEditText` but it makes the whole text bold.

How can i make it possible? Please help me?

Comment: You will need to wait until I add support for that, most likely.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your on button code? How do you use `applyEffect(effect, value);`

Comment: @AndroidKid: Use typeface or Spannable string.

Comment: @Sunny I implemented the above method. applyEffect(effect, value); uses value - true to set effect and false to remove effect.